# UITextField becomes first responder when view becomes visible, but I don't want it to

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

This should be simple, but it's becoming a headache. I have a view with a UITextField where the user types some text and clicks search. This pops up another view controller, and I resign first responder on the text field before the first view disappears. When the second view gets dismissed, the first view automatically makes the text field become first responder again and I can't find a way to suppress this. Does anyone have any idea how I can keep the keyboard from popping up when I dismiss the second view?

I tried to resignFirstResponder in viewWillAppear, no effect. I tried the same in viewDidAppear, but the keyboard pops up and then immediately dismisses which is awkward looking.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: “I resign first responder on the text field before the first view disappears.”  When, precisely, do you tell the text field to resign first responder?  In what method?

Comment: I resign first responder in viewWillDisappear, and you can see the keyboard dismiss before the second view becomes visible, but when I dismiss the second view, it disappears, then the keyboard animates up from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Is viewcontroller made in Interface Builder? You might want to make sure that there is no option set in IB that causes this (the view controller's firstresponder set as the UITextView, or UITextView's becomeFirstResponder being set)

Comment: There is no nib file associated with either of the view controllers.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any solution found??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a fix, but its not a very good one.

Found that canBecomeResponder message was being passed to the textfield right after `viewWillAppear` and before `viewDidAppear`.

So I set a BOOL value in `viewDidAppear` to YES, and used that value in `textField:shouldBeginEditing` method. Basically if the `viewDidAppear` was not called yet, `textField:shouldBeginEditing` was returning NO.

Comment: I'm still not sure why this was an issue in the first place, but your solutions is basically what I ended up doing to fix it. I set a flag in `viewDidAppear` and unset it in `viewDidDisappear` and used that to determine whether or not the text field should become active.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - a UITextView in View Controller A was the first responder. When tapping another UI element on the screen I pushed View Controller B onto the nav stack, but when the back button was pushed and View Controller A was shown again, the UITextView was still first responder.

I solved the issue by calling `resignFirstResponder` on the text view in View Controller A's `viewWillDisappear`. Note that this does *not* work if you call it in `viewDidDisappear`, since at that point the text view is no longer first responder. It's important to make sure that the text view is actually the first responder when you call `resignFirstResponder`, otherwise resigning has no effect. You can check this for debugging purposes by inspecting `isFirstResponder` on the text view.

Answer (score 0):

**Please add those Line in your code in my case "tfCode1"**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    _ = self.tfCode1.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   _ = self.tfCode1.resignFirstResponder()
}
```